# Java changed element in an Arraylist - need to keep previous & modify the rest

Tags: java, arraylist

My program is a train schedule that shows cities with their arrival and departure times. In the program, the "Delay" input prompts you to type the city name and number of minutes to add a delay in minutes to that city's arrival time. This information is all stored in a ArrayList

### Here is a link to my current output: [Train Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIfbp.png)

This is my delay method:

```
public void delay(String station, int minutes) {
    // negative delay in minutes are allowed but no guarantee of the
    // consistency of schedules of previous stations
    boolean startDelay = false;
    ListIterator<Station> sIt = schedule.listIterator();
    while (sIt.hasNext()) {

        // first find out the index of station
        Station currStation = sIt.next();

        if (!startDelay && currStation.getCity().equals(station)) {
            startDelay = true;

        } else {
            currStation.delay(minutes);

        }
    }
    startDelay = false;
}
```

---

However, it is this point where I have to add those same minutes to the rest of the times on the list but not have it apply those changes to cities before the delay was implemented.

For example, if I type in "Edmonton" and "30", the output should look like this:

[Link to what output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avjho.png)

---

This is my main method:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        ArrayList<Station> schedule = new ArrayList<Station>();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d HH:mm");
        schedule.add(new Station(null, sdf.parse("1 20:30"), "Vancouver"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("2 06:00"), sdf.parse("2 06:35"), "Kamloops"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("2 16:00"), sdf.parse("2 17:30"), "Jasper"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("2 23:00"), sdf.parse("2 23:59"), "Edmonton"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("3 08:00"), sdf.parse("3 08:25"), "Saskatoon"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("3 20:45"), sdf.parse("3 22:30"), "Winnipeg"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("4 05:02"), sdf.parse("4 05:42"), "Sioux Lookout"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("4 15:35"), sdf.parse("4 16:10"), "Hornepayne"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("5 00:18"), sdf.parse("5 00:48"), "Capreol"));
        schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("5 09:30"), null, "Toronto"));

        TrainTimeTable ttt = new TrainTimeTable(schedule);
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cmd = "";
        System.out.println(("Timetable for a train travelling between Vancouver and Toronto").toUpperCase());
        while (!cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {

            System.out.print("Input [Quit | Delay | Show] timetable: ");
            cmd = inp.next();
            if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Show")) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\t\tSHOWING TRAIN SCHEDULE: ");
                ttt.displaySchedule();
            } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Delay")) {

                System.out.print("Please enter the station where train is delayed: ");
                String station = inp.next();

                System.out.print("Please enter the delay time in minutes: ");
                int minutes = inp.nextInt();
                ttt.delay(station, minutes);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\t\tSHOWING NEW SCHEDULE: ");
                ttt.displaySchedule();

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        inp.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Text is not image.

Comment: I don't know what Java actually parses for "d HH:mm" but it could be day, hours and minutes of year 0 of the Gregorian calendar.  Which might cause some real weirdness.  I think I'd rather roll my own date for a simple assignment like this and avoid any possible errors using a rather complex library.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I was wondering how I can modify specific elements and not the entire ArrayList? Say I wanted to delay the station named Jasper for 30 minutes. How can I do that so only that station and the ones following that changes and not all the stations?

Comment: @user202729 sorry I'm new here :( I'm currently out of luck which is why I even created an account

Comment: Try using `ArrayList.set` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor modification should fix your problem. When the station name matches, set startDelay to true and dd the delay for this and all following stations.

```
public void delay(String station, int minutes) {
  boolean startDelay = false;
  ListIterator<Station> sIt = schedule.listIterator();
  while (sIt.hasNext()) {
    Station currStation = sIt.next();
    if (!startDelay && currStation.getCity().equals(station)) {
      startDelay = true;
    }
    if( startDelay ){
      currStation.delay(minutes);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit, following David's suggestion: simplify the method body,

```
boolean startDelay = false;
for( Station currStation: schedule ){
  if ...
  if ...
}
```

Comment: Also, you can switch to a for-each loop.

Comment: I would not use a String for arrival and departure times. Store these times as minutes from day 1, midnight, and add a formatting routine for `Station.toString`. Simplifies the delay calculation.

Comment: @laune thank you very much!! It worked! :) I also added the ignoreCaseMethod() - to the if statement >> if (!startDelay && currStation.getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(station)) {